# How best store year, month, and day to core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I need to save my data from a chart:

`var labelsOfMonth = [String]() 
var dataOfMonth = [Double]()`

And than store to a dictionary the Year and month

Please help me to understand how to implement that, and save to CoreData

Comment: Can't you use NSDate for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should store just the date and the data. Your entity could look like this:

```
DataPoint
   - data : NSNumber
   - date : NSDate
```

You can ignore all details of the date and just extract month and year like this:

```
let month = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: dataPoint.date)
let year = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: dataPoint.date)
```

Comment: But if  month  changes, how store new data for new month and saved previous ?

Comment: You make a new `DataPoint` with the new date. Duh.